# CSS input:focus and border-color issues

Tags: html, css, input, bootstrap-4, frontend

## The problem

I'm currently working on a project where I build a frontend using bootstrap4. To match the CI, I changed the highlighting colour of inputs to match the companies main colour scheme.

Basically I did the following:

```css
:root{
    --custom-red: #871d33;
}

...

input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus{
    border-color: var(--custom-red);
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--custom-red);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--custom-red);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--custom-red);
}
```

Which produces the following result in a form (Firefox), which is alright: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiqQN.png)

But somehow date input fields are messed up in a strange way as soon as a value has been selected; take a look: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDhIR.png) Interestingly, the cropping problem is reseted as soon as the viewport is resized, which means there is some kind of rendering issue.

Now I was looking around what was happening to my date fields and ended up detecting the source: `border-color: var(--custom-red);`
As soon as I remove this line from my css and therefore stick with the default bootstrap-blue highlighting everything works as expected - no more cropping.

I found out, that somehow there is a 8px border-left and border-right setting, hidden somewhere, since this setting does not appear on the element inspector but the values can clearly be seen on the box values: [Screenshot before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8252m.png)
Interestingly, these 8px settings change, when I re-add my css back again and :focus on my field: [Screenshot after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqin2.png)

Since I was not editing anything on the `border-left` or `border-right` parameter I could not get my head around what was going on. My suggestion now is, that `border-color` somehow 'resets' other `border-xy` settings silently in the background. That sounds completely crazy in my opinion but I even noticed, that `border-radius` is definitely overwritten, when :focus is triggered. Take a look on this (need to zoom in): [border-radius unfocused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC6G2.png), [border-radius focused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75CDp.png)

## Testing on other browsers

### Update

I just discovered that `outline: none;` removes the default chrome based :focus behaviour and uses the desired css like a fallback. This way the behaviour on chrome based browsers is at least now similar to the one on Firefox but on Firefox the cropping issue still stays the same.

### Original

Now I was not sure whether this is maybe a browser based issue, so I checked on chrome based browsers as well and ... well it looks like :focus is here something totally different, than clicking into the field!
Triggering :focus using the element inspector gives the expected result: [Screenshot inspector based triggering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVLiq.png)
But simply clicking into the field only 'highlights' it darkish for some reason:
[Screenshot manually clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IyFY.png)
Interestingly, one can see the overwritten `border-radius` on this example even more, than on Firefox!

Despite the fact I do not understand why there are obviously two different types of 'focusing' in chrome based browsers, the date field is working as expected and not cropping off content: *Sorry, had to remove this screenshot for I have not enough points, yet*

## End

So now I'm completely confused:

1. Why is `border-color` behaving as it behaves under Firefox? Did somebody ever encounter anything like that?
2. Why are there different :focus triggers on chrome based browsers, despite the fact :focus is listed as supported by GoogleChrome and derivatives?

I need some fresh coffee now. Thanks for every reply!

## Example code

As requested, here you go:

```css
input:focus{
  outline: none;
  border-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px red;
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

Answer (score 6):

## Workaround

So I could not find any root for this problem but I found at least a workaround by adding custom default border settings as well:

```css
input{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 0.2rem;
    padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
}

input:focus{
    outline: none;
    border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
```

This way the default behaviour is overwritten and the date input finally working as expected.

But still - I would like to know what is happening in the default case?